# Plugin com.squareup.sqldelight in build.gradle of Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

Today I created an empty **Kotlin Multiplatform App** in **Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1** and I added only one line in plugin section of `build.gradle` of `shared` folder :

```
id("com.squareup.sqldelight") version "1.5.5"
```

and after pressing **Sync** button I've got an error

```
shared/build.gradle.kts:9:5: Unresolved reference: androidTarget
```

I am sure it's not about wrong initial file structure, it's about **sqldelight** plugin line itself - bad syntax or so.
For reference I leave here some files:

`build.gradle.kts` of shared folder (only first lines):

```
    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
        alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
        id("com.squareup.sqldelight") version "1.5.5"//this line was added only
    }
    
    kotlin {
        androidTarget {
            compilations.all {
                kotlinOptions {
                    jvmTarget = "1.8"
                }
            }
        }
....
```

`build.gradle.kts` of the project (all lines):

```
plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid).apply(false)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform).apply(false)
}
```

`libs.versions.toml` (all lines)

```
[versions]
agp = "8.2.0"
kotlin = "1.9.20"
compose = "1.5.4"
compose-compiler = "1.5.4"
compose-material3 = "1.1.2"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.8.0"

[libraries]
kotlin-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test", version.ref = "kotlin" }
androidx-activity-compose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
compose-ui = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling-preview = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-foundation = { module = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-material3 = { module = "androidx.compose.material3:material3", version.ref = "compose-material3" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinCocoapods = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

I also tried another syntax with that plugin, in `build.gradle` of shared I added

```
alias(libs.plugins.sqldelightPlugin)
```

and in `libs.versions.toml` I added

```
[versions]
....
sqldelight = "1.5.5"

[plugins]
....
sqldelightPlugin = { id = "com.squareup.sqldelight", version.ref = "sqldelight" }
```

But anyway I am getting the same error.

How correctly add `com.squareup.sqldelight` plugin into shared `build.gradle` of **Kotlin Multiplatform** project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Latest version

For the latest version, use:

```
plugins {
   id("app.cash.sqldelight") version "2.0.1"
}
```

See the [documentation](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.1/android_sqlite/).

##### Old version

Ending with version 1.5.5 they published it under a different plugin id, and not on the Gradle plugin portal. If you must have 1.5.5 you need to use:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.5.5")
  }
}

apply(plugin = "com.squareup.sqldelight")
```

See the [old documentation](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/1.5.4/android_sqlite/).

Comment: it's almost correct, but in build.gradle.kts instead of "apply" I have to write id("com.squareup.sqldelight")

Comment: You can use either the `id` or `apply` notation if you declare the buildscript dependency in the root project but the plugin in a subproject. If both are in the same project you need to use `apply`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript. That behaviour is because of the special status of the `plugins` block, which is compiled separately so it doesn't see dependencies declared in a `buildscript` block from the same script. Also, note my second block of code is just a copy/paste from the sqldelight documentation (save for upping the version).